# How to display drupal user page tabs on 3 different page

Tags: users

We want to display a 3 tab  "Create new account(Lawyer Registration)" , "Log In" , "Forgot Password" link on 3 different pages. when we click on log in then they display all 3 tabs.

Actually we have 2 different type of registration process one for lawyer and another one is for normal user. when we click to login then they display above 3 tabs and this is confusing for user. so i want to hide this lawyer registration process form user page and call them to from different page.

So please help me how i can remove them from above tabs and call user/register page from different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution to hide the tabs is to change the menu type form tabs to callback:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/login']['type']    = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/register']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/password']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

You could render the user register form whatever you want with this:

```
$elements = drupal_get_form("user_register_form"); 
$form = drupal_render($elements);
echo $form;
```

Comment: I put that code in user.module but nothing happens.

Comment: You need to put the hook function in a new custom module and clear the caché, also rename "yourmodule" with your module name.

Comment: actually i am new to drupal. i dont know how to create a hook menu.please guide me

Comment: Second code is working fine.Now i just need to remove them form user page.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial to create your first module: https://www.drupal.org/node/1074362 :)

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible with the use of Profile2 module (https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) in combination with Profile2 regpath module (https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath)

This way you can setup a specific registration path per profile.